# Determine Destination IndexPath when scrollView flicks (ends dragging)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

So, I have a infinite scrolling tableView of same size cells. Each cell has just a single image and what I'm trying to achieve is that as soon as a scroll flick happens, I'm trying to determine at what indexPath it will arrive at and preload Images for that index only.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let contentOffset = CGPoint(x: targetContentOffset.pointee.x, y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)
    let totalRowsVisible = Int(tableView.bounds.height / rowHeight) + 1

    let rowNumber = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: contentOffset)?.row ?? Int((contentOffset.y + offSetParameter) / rowHeight)
}
```

Right now this is what I'm using to determine the indexPath of tableview as soon as dragging ends but this is giving me incorrect results many times (especially when I scroll really fast).

Also when I add more rows to the tableView (at the bottom), the contentOffset changes weirdly and targetContentOffset Parameter is loaded somewhere else.

I have not found any solution anywhere.

EDIT: So, in the comments people have asked my specific requirement. The requirement exactly is as stated, that whenever a scroll begins and dragging ends, I have to determine what destination the scroll will end at and begin fetching content for that row before reaching the destination. So no matter how fast or slow the scroll occurs I just download images for the indexPath

Comment: maybe you should look into `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching`. [Ref: Prefetching for UITableView](https://andreygordeev.com/2017/02/20/uitableview-prefetching/). Not exactly what you want but an alternate solution.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Thanks but my requirement is very specific and that wouldn't work for me

Comment: Yes, true that but when you scroll the `tableView`, the corresponding `cellForRowAt:` is going to be called in quick succession anyways. You probably have the logic to load the image here. Btw, what do you exactly plan to do in `scrollViewWillEndDragging`?

Comment: see I plan on loading only the images that will be visible as soon as the scroll ends.
`cellforRowAtIndexPath` will get called on all the rows in the middle also and I dont want to load the images for them.

Comment: You cannot stop calling `cellForRowAt:`; it's automatic. You, technically, could put logic to block the data loading part and do all sorts of tricks in `cellForRowAt:` but it's better to go with `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching`. It handles the cancel prefetch part, if... optimization is your "special requirement" but anyways, check [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12383568/2857130) discouraging your requirement.

Comment: OK. 1. I don't think users will use an app like this ever where they flick and then wait for it to land on a destination. So you'll always deal with user interactions that you can't predict. 2. If you're determined to do this, you'd best gather some data on flicks and use that to do regression on. You shouldn't need too many of them to figure it out.

Comment: @Alper the point is that once scroll begins, only the content that is going  to be viewed should load and not the ones in the middle. So its not like the user will wait for it to land but if the user scrolls very fast then no point loading the content in middle rows.
Only the content that will be eventually visible should be loaded, is what the requirement is.

Also could you suggest how to get data on flicks and do regression on it? I dont understand how to go about that?

Comment: @staticVoidMan The prefetching API will just tell me what out of view rows it will load. But it will not tell me about the destination indexPaths and there is no parameter on which I can judge whether to cancel prefetch since I dont know where the scroll will end

Comment: I have't dived into the prefetching API, but if it tells you which view rows it will load, how are _those_ `indexPaths` (which have row information) different from what you need?

Comment: Also, what is your "very specific requirement"? Can you please state that as clearly as possible in the question?

Comment: @Aaron Hi, I've mentioned it in the question. Please tell me if you have any questions

Comment: @suyashKD, I know this is frustrating, but I think your request is still confusing: `scroll begins and dragging ends` did the user flick the screen? Or did they drag it? I think you need to be more specific. Also, can you explain why `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching ` does not work?

Comment: I think part of the confusion is that the scrolling API doesn't tell you where it will "end" and what `indexPath` that will be. It does tell you when scrolling ended, however. The problem with that is, if you're constantly adjusting the number of rows in your table view the scrolling API is going to be even more confusing as a means of deriving an answer. The `indexPath` that will be visible can be derived from `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` however. Not the scrolling API.

Comment: One piece of information that will really help with this is knowing how many total images you will ever need to scroll through. If you knew that you could tell the `tableView` exactly how tall it should be and thus you will have the exact number of rows and your scroll indicator will be accurate. Then it would be a matter of figuring out how to queue up the right set of requests for images.